# how do I handle worksheet not found error?

Tags: python, pandas, worksheet, except

I'm trying out to continue to the next iteration if the worksheet I'm trying to import does no exist. I got this command " except FileNotFoundError:" but actually this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks all of you, Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

list = ["a.xlsx","b.xlsx","c.xlsx"]

for f in list:
 try :
   df1 = pd.read_excel(f, 'a1')
 except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: What error is raised when worksheet does not exist? Please Include stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You aren't catching the correct error.

### Solution

Stack trace specifies error raised is `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError`. Import the error from `xldd.biffh`, then catch and handle the exception.

## Example

```
import pandas as pd
from xlrd.biffh import XLRDError

list = ["a.xlsx","b.xlsx","c.xlsx"]

for f in list:
 try:
   df1 = pd.read_excel(f, 'a1')
 except FileNotFoundError as e:
   print(e)
 except XLRDError as e:
   print(e)
```

https://repl.it/repls/DarlingKhakiRecursion#main.py